# Python pandas get max value from mysql

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I execute statement

```
sequence = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT MAX(_SequenceNumber) AS sequence_number FROM betting.betting', database)
```

get dataframe

```
   sequence_number
0             4495
```

I can't figure out how to get just 4495 I was trying something like

```
sequence = dataframe.iloc[0]
```

Still does not give me

```
sequence = 4495
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: You mean you want the dataframe without the index and column header? Or you just want the int value result?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) or [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) for [fast scalar value getting](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting):

```
print dataframe.at[0, 'sequence_number']
4495

print dataframe.sequence_number.iat[0]
4495

print type(dataframe.at[0, 'sequence_number'])
<type 'numpy.int64'>

print type(dataframe.sequence_number.iat[0])
<type 'numpy.int64'>
```

Answer (score 0):

`read_sql_query` returns a dataframe.  As suggested by @jezrael, `iat` is the best method for accessing a scalar in a dataframe.

If you use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/), however, there is also a `scalar` function which returns the first element of the first result, None if there is no result, or an error if there is more than one result.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, MetaData, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# Connection set-up.
engine = create_engine(...)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
metadata = MetaData()

my_table = Table('betting.betting', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

# Query scalar.
>>> session.query(func.max(my_table.c._SequenceNumber)).scalar()
52
```